# How to deny Windows Credential Password Prompt everytime when operate remote windows service in powershell?

Tags: security, powershell

Below is my code:

```
$s = Get-WmiObject -computer 10.10.zz.zz Win32_Service -Filter "Name='XXX'" -credential (Get-Credential XXXXXX\fanwx)
$s.stopservice()
copy-item D:\.....\aaa.exe -destination \\10.10.zz.zz\c$\vvv\
copy-item D:\.....\aaa.pdb -destination \\10.10.zz.zz\c$\vvv\
```

$s.startservice()

everytime executed, will be prompted enter the password of the remote server. Is there a way allowed me only enter once in powershell OR read the credential in Credential Manager?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just start by

```
$cred = Get-Credential "XXXXXX\fanwx"
```

and after :

```
$s = Get-WmiObject -computer 10.10.zz.zz Win32_Service -Filter "Name='XXX'" -credential $cred
```

You can put the password on the disk :

```
PS > $cred.Password | ConvertFrom-SecureString | Set-Content c:\temp\password.txt
```

And retreive it with :

```
$password = Get-Content c:\temp\password.txt | ConvertTo-SecureString
$cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PsCredential "UserName",$password
```